# How can I display an input view on bixby with pre-populated selections AND a custom input field?

Tags: bixby

Currently I am trying to set up a few continuation actions after an interaction. One such continuation will send an email to the user with the results from the last action. I set up the action that will get an email address and send the email. To fill this input, i would like to offer the email addresses contained in the `profile`/`self` capsule as selection options and alternatively allow the user to input a custom email.

i set up a default input to get email addresses from the `profile` capsule and then offer those as options for the email input:

```
input (emailAddress) {
  type (contact.EmailAddress)
  instantiation-behavior (ShowDefaultValueDecision)
  min (Required) max (One)
  default-init {
    intent {
      goal: ReturnSelfEmail
    }
  }
}
```

Then i display them in an `input-view` using `selection-of`:

Here is my view:

```
input-view {
  match: contact.EmailAddress(this) {
    to-input: EmailResults
  }
  message ("What is your Email address?")
  render{
    selection-of (this) {
      where-each (email) {
        paragraph {
          value {
            template ("#{value(email)}")
          }
          style (Detail_M)
        }
      }
    }
    form {
      elements {
        text-input {
          id (emailAddress)
          label("Email Address")
          required (true)
          type (contact.EmailAddress)
        }
      }
      on-submit {
        goal: contact.EmailAddress
        value: viv.core.FormElement(emailAddress)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In that view, I tried to add a `form` component as well but this does not work. Any ideas on how to have a custom input option in addition to the selections? Or another way to deal with a situation where the selections do not satisfy the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render a `form` after you've rendered a `selection-of`.

My IDE shows this error - does yours?

"Unreachable statement" means that that part of the code will never run.
[image]

Anyways, one possible way to model this is to offer a selection view of the user's real email addresses, and one final entry which is a dummy email address called "input my own." (this uses `selection-of`)

If that selection is made, you can do throw an [error](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/error-handling) in your JavaScript, and replan to a goal such as `EnterCustomEmail`.  (this uses the `form`).

Comment: Yes, got that error but it still ran so i figured it was worth a shot. Anyway, I set this up and it seems to work! Thanks for the creative solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach the problem.

In the `result-view` of the interaction (assuming that the email is sent at the end of the interaction), I would ask the user a `followup` question "Should I send a confirmation email to the `<email>` on your profile.?"

If the user responds "Yes" then the `Action` associated with the `goal` for the `on-confirm` will send an email to the user.

If the user says "No", the `Action` associated with the `goal` for `on-deny` should prompt the user for an email address.

This approach uses the conversational features of the Bixby platform and makes this interaction a more natural experience for the end-user.

Comment: This is a great solution. much cleaner than everything else i've tried, but in this particular situation, the user can say a few continuations. As far as I can tell, a follow-up seems to conflict with having continuations, is this correct? Sorry for not clarifying that in the original question